# Change netmask subnet on server due to reduced IP range allocation

Tags: networking, ip, ubuntu-22.04, ipconfig

I am running a few Ubuntu 22.04 servers, each with one IPv4 address configured.

Currently with a /24 network allocation, the datacenter requested some IP's back, and now I am left with a /28, which is fine.

None of the IP's returned were in use. I am wondering if I need to reconfigure the IP configuration to account for the new /28 situation.

Running `ip a` shows `inet 123.123.123.123/24`, should I change this to `inet 123.123.123.123/28`. If not, can someone explain why not?

Full `ip a` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:00:00:6d:6a:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 123.123.123.123/24 brd 123.123.123.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends. To make sure you should ask the datacenter guys, they must know.

If you've got a routed subnet of your own, then you might need to change the mask. Not doing so prevents your servers from talking to the others servers from the previous /24 subnet - so you might not even care.

However, if your subnet is shared with other servers, then no, don't change the mask. A clear indication for that is when the default gateway address is outside the /28 subnet.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference it would make to change the subnet mask would be the broadcast address, you can see it written after brd.
Now you have the broadcast as 123.123.123.255, with a /28 it would be 123.123.123.127

If you're sure your machine won't need to use the broadcast IP then don't change it but I would correct that just to avoid any possible issue.

Comment: As Zac67 points out, there's more nuances to this than your answer shows.

Comment: Zac is referring to the case in which the datacenter administrators are routing that subnet as a 24 but giving you just the addresses in the /28. In that case you would need to keep the subnet mask as it is. But I expect that they gave you a proper subnet /28 with its gateway and broadcast address, in this case you should change it to a /28.
I definetely agree with Zac in that you need to ask them in what situation you're in